# Is there an alternative to innerHTML? - issue on Blackberry browser

Tags: javascript, blackberry, innerhtml

Is there an alternative to innerHTML? - issue on Blackberry browser

Blackberry 4.6 browser does not seem to use innerHTML properly.
Instead of replacing contents, it appends contents!

```
function load_activities(){
    x$('#dummy').xhr('program.php',{
    method:'post', 
    data:   'action=list'.              
    callback: function(){
            document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }       
    });
```

Comment: What happens if you set innerHTML to empty string? Does it still keep the old stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about cloning the node without children and then adding the new content?

```
callback: function () {
    var status2 = document.getElementById("status2");
    var copy = status2.cloneNode(false); // false indicates to not copy children
    copy.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    if (status2.nextSibling) {  // put the copy in the same place as the existing node
        var refchild = status2.nextSibling;
        status2.parentNode.removeChild(status2);
        refchild.parentNode.insertBefore(copy, refchild);
    }
    else { // existing node is the last child, copy can be appended to the end of the list
        var parent = status2.parentNode;
        parent.removeChild(status2);
        parent.appendChild(copy);
    }
}
```

I have no way to test this, so I don't know for sure that `cloneNode` will work as expected and only copy the tags and attributes. Hope it helps.